# autocomplete box likes stackoverflow's tags box

Tags: c#, asp.net, stack-overflow, autocompletebox

I want to use auto complete box likes stackoverflow's tags box ,

[image: Stackoverflow's auto complete box]

Can you show me some examples or links that can be reference ?
Thanks :)

Comment: This may help: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Answer (score 2):

Chosen is a JavaScript plugin that makes long, unwieldy select boxes much more user-friendly

[Here](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) is the article and demo available.

```
   $(".select").chosen();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create database or container for elements to autocomplete and in **TextChanged** handler of the input textbox ask your database or container for matches.